# Can Visual Studio's Code Analysis checks for compiler generated code be disabled?

Tags: c#, code-analysis, stylecop

In my code base I've got a bunch of testing code that looks like this:

```
// define proxy that I can assign my own delegate to
protected delegate void VerifyStop();
protected VerifyStop StopProxy { get; set; }

// in the test code assign a delegate appropriate for what I'm testing...
this.StopProxy = () =>
{
    notificationWasSent = true;
    Assert.AreEqual(....);
};

// call framework code that will eventually call my StopProxy code.
```

The framework I'm testing calls the StopProxy method and this lets me set a lambda to verify the framework behaviour.

When I run the `Visual Studio` code analysis I get warnings about unused private fields from code the compiler writes from the lambda I give it.

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1823:AvoidUnusedPrivateFields", Scope = "member", Target = "AutoTraderTest.PairOpenClose1ATest+<>c__DisplayClass12.#CS$<>8__localsd")]
```

Currently I just ignore them individually in the test project's  `GlobalSuppression.cs` file,but given each test can have 5 lambda's and I can have 100's of tests, this makes for many intentionally disabled warnings.  This also makes the `GlobalSuppression.cs` file hard to parse through.

I like the warning for code that I generate, but for autogenerated code Is there a way to turn off this error without resorting to ignoring each instance?

I've looked at this question:

[How to configure StyleCop to suppress warnings on generated code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590238/how-to-configure-stylecop-to-suppress-warnings-on-generated-code)

but it talks about disabling checks for the entire file, not compiler generated code, which is something that I don't want.

Comment: Using code analysis on a test project strikes me as very unproductive.  Use it on the final project, the one where the class is *really* used.

Comment: @Hans,  I agree with you on this.  However, for the purpose of this question can we assume this production code or that I don't have a choice in the matter?

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever.  If production code produces these warnings then you should **not** ignore them.

Comment: @Hans, then maybe its my lack of understanding but if I create a lambda like above that is used, I still get the code analysis warning about unused code. Where the unused code is compiler generated.

Comment: Could you please post a short, compilable code sample that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @HansPassant: Correctness, readability, and maintainability verifications can be just as important (or maybe at least "almost as important" <g>) for test code as for production code.  I'd have to very much disagree that running static analysis against test code is counterproductive when one values the quality of that test code.  Granted, test code isn't equally valued on every project or product, but when it is...

Comment: Broad strokes, doesn't have much to do with the question.  If you suppress messages to get happy code analysis on a test project and they actually *hide* messages in the production code that should not be hidden then it is no longer correct anymore of course.  Doesn't exactly improve readability and maintainability either.